# "sudo apt-get install" on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, install

My understanding is that you need to install 'Fink' before an apt-get will work in the Terminal on OS X, but there isn't a Fink binary installer yet for Mavericks.

Does anyone know what the best alternative would be for

```
sudo apt-get install
```

on OS X Mavericks?

Comment: Fink has been release for Mavericks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want a package manager.

`apt-get` is just an interface for Aptitude, a `deb` packaging system. DEB isn't tied into Mac OS like it would be your average Linux distro, so you'd need an alternative.

Fink will do this on its own, other alternatives are `MacPorts` or `Homebrew`.

If your goal is to be able to execute a command, say like `(something) install program` and it'll install the program and its dependencies for you, either of these three will do that for you.

I'd personally suggest Homebrew. http://brew.sh/

Comment: the formulas aren't always there in brew though.  I wish there was a clearer "formula" for porting apt-get packages to brew

Answer (score 2):

Fink has been released for OS X Mavericks. Per their [latest news item](http://feeds2.feedburner.com/FinkProjectNews-en)…

> 2013-10-30: **fink-0.36.0 released.**
>   `fink-0.36.0` was released on 31 October, 2013. This is the first release to work with OS X 10.9 (Mavericks). We are currently in the process of making packages available.

You can download Fink from [fink.thetis.ig42.org](http://fink.thetis.ig42.org/download/index.php).